# Logic App only reading a few Service Bus messages before timeout

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App which is triggered by an EventGrid topic but reads messages from a Service Bus queue using the SessionId passed in the event.

The Service Bus peek read is done in an Until loop which exits when the Service Bus peek read times out. (I have set the timeout to 30S in the settings for the Action).

The problem I have is that only around 20 messages are read before the loop exits despite the queue being full. Why is this?

The loop looks like this:
[image: Service Bus reading loop]

Comment: If you look at the logic app history. how long your loop is running for ?

Comment: @Thomas 31s, which is just over the timeout time I set. I'm struggling to understand what is happening here: each Peek Action is taking <1s, even the last, so why is it timing out? It's as if the accumulated time is being used for the timeout.

Comment: I have changed the condition of the Until loop (and inner Condition Action) to check for a message of 0 length rather than an ActionTimeOut. This has had no effect, the Until loop runs for 30s then exits even though there are many more messages to process.

Comment: I also tried increasing the timeout for the Peek Action from 30s to 1m but this has had no effect, the Loop still exits after 30s.

Comment: Can you explain what you try to achieve ? not sure if logic app are design to do what you re doing

Comment: @Thomas, it's working fine now. The problem was caused by the time limit being set for for the Until loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Thomas gave me the clue that got me there in the end.

Unknown to me Until loops have "limits" settings for timeout and number of iterations.

Clicking the "change limits" link reveals these settings so that they can be  overridden.